# ASPxGridView - when I submit changes I always see them from one edit before

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

I've got a problem with GridView on my WebForms page. I hope maybe you can help me.

I've got a Grid binded by LinqDataSource through Entity Framework to SQL Server view. View basically aggregates data from one of the tables. On my page I allow to make some changes to that table, which I update with Entity Framework in different context. The problem is that after PostBack I always see changes from one edit before.

For example:
1. I've got entity with value "Matthew".
2. I edit to "John" -> postback => I see "Matthew".
3. I edit to "Mick" -> postback => I see "John".

I tried disabling grid's view state and rows caching - without success.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

```
                <p>
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="WebApplication2.Database1Entities" EntityTypeName="" TableName="Clients">
                </asp:LinqDataSource>
                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" KeyFieldName="id" EnableRowsCache="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="id" VisibleIndex="0">
                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="name" VisibleIndex="1">
                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
            </p>
            <p>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px">
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click">
                </dx:ASPxButton>
            </p>


    protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var ent = new Database1Entities();
                var itemToUpdate = ent.Clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == 1);
                itemToUpdate.name = ASPxTextBox1.Text;
                ent.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: show ur edit function and grid view bind function

Answer (score 0):

Matthew,

I recommend that you use the ASPxGridView's editing events. Take a look at this example:

- [How to implement common scenarios within the ASPxGridView bound with the EntityDataSource / Entity Framework](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3251.aspx)

It's a Code Central example so you can download the whole solution and run it locally:

- [How to use Code Central](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2008/07/30/codecentral-source-code-to-search-download-run-enterprise-cheat.aspx)

If that still doesn't help then contact the DevExpress support team and they can help you:
[DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question)